# "ImportError: No module named twilio.rest"

Tags: python, twilio

I have installed python 2.7.10 with PATH access and correctly installed twilio.  However, when I try to execute a code I get this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tmslvo\Google Drive\Desktop\send text.py", line 1, in <module>
    from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
ImportError: No module named twilio.rest
```

Now I read that a reason might be that python can't find the twilio package so I tried the

```
which -a python
which -a twilio
```

commands (in my Windows command prompt) in which case I get

```
'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Does anybody have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: What did you use to install Twilio?

Comment: pip install twilio and it seemed to worked fine

Comment: Is that what you meant?  I used the command prompt (in administrator mode) in windows 10.

Comment: Yeah.. that looks correct.... is python working OK?

Comment: Yes, it is.  I just checked the twilio version through the command prompt and it confirms that I have installed 5.3.0 - but I still get the same error when trying to execute my code.

Comment: Then again, when I type import twilio in idle I get "no module named twilio".  When I check the python27 folder there is a twilio folder in the site-packages folder, but no twilio.py

Comment: And are you sure you only have one version of python installed? try running `python --version`

Comment: And just out of curiosity, you don't have any files called twilio.py in your project right?

Comment: No, I didn't have twilio.py files in my project.  And I only have one python version.

Comment: Ok, this is really odd. I would suggest trying to install it again then.

Comment: I just did and now it works!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad you did. I've added an answer going through the steps we went over for future reference. Please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I followed the tips above. Using Mac OS 11.3, I renamed the file from twilio.py to sms.py and ran "pip install twilio" I was then able to run the program successfully.

Answer (score 57):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think your problem will be that somehow when you installed the library, it failed silently(?). A few things to keep in mind:

1. When installing Python libraries, always make sure you use [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip).
2. Also, check that none of your files within the project are actually called `twilio.py` as this will conflict with the actual library.
3. Check that you're using the version of Python you think you're using by running `python --version`

All that failing, run the installation again, and all going well (without errors), you should be able to test it quickly with the [following code](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages).

```
import twilio
import twilio.rest

try:
    client = twilio.rest.TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

    message = client.messages.create(
        body="Hello World",
        to="+14159352345",
        from_="+14158141829"
    )
except twilio.TwilioRestException as e:
    print e
```

Comment: Point 2 helped me. After I renamed file from `twilio.py` to other name, it works.

Comment: I am still struggling with the same issue. I am using python version 2.7.13 and installed twilio via pip install twilio. It says "Successfully installed twilio-5.7.0". When I run the sample code, I get the error "No module named twilio".

Comment: +1. Had a source dir called twilio, and issued from twilio.utils import some_func. Renaming it to another name fixes the issue.

Comment: I think your pip is not configured properly . You may be getting succefuuly installed message but it is not install where it should be. try  pip install --user <package name > i am sure it will work for you. pip install will work fine only n virtualenvironment.

Comment: Yep, I had a test file called `twilio.py`. I renamed it to `twilio-test.py` and everything worked.

Comment: It should be noted in #2 you may also not name your script with a twilio prefix either. I initially had twilio-sample.py and renaming to twillz.py resolved.

Comment: point two it help me.

Comment: Thanks, the point 2 helped me!!. =)

Answer (score 11):

I had this problem as well.

In my case, I had named my file `twilio.py` and that is what caused the error.

Renaming the file to `send_sms.py` ( or any other name of your choice) will resolve the issue!

Answer (score 9):

try this: sudo pip3 install twilio --upgrade

Answer (score 2):

Close and then relunch all IDLE instances.

This sounds obvious but it worked for me, since the installations of components were successful

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue. I had used easy_install instead of pip to install twilio which was the problem. To fix this I ran `pip uninstall twilio` and reinstalled using pip.

Answer (score 1):

rename file name other than twilio.py
EX:send_sms.py

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party here but I also ran into this issue.
After some trial and error, it looks like it was due to the pip version I was using. I originally used -
`pip3 install twilio`.

Now I'm unsure of the underlying reason why this did not work, but it seems that pip3 does not encompass all versions of python 3.x? Using
`pip3 list` and
`pip3.8 list`
 I noticed I had the twilio module for pip3 but not for pip 3.8.

I used the following and was able to solve the issue
`pip3.8 install twilio`. 
I used `pip3.8` because that matched the python3.8 version that I am using.

Comment: Ran into similar problem, this worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pycharm user:

Macs (mid 2017) come with `python 2.6` and `2.7` installed. `PyCharm` uses by default `2.6`. When you install `twilio` (Pip install) the module is installed in python version `2.7`. So, when you try to run `twilio` from `PyCharm` you get

`ImportError: No module named twilio.rest`

Solution: change the python interpreter in `PyCharm`. Go to `preferences > project interpreter` and from the drop menu `Project Interpreter` choose `python 2.7`

Answer (score 0):

I think your pip is not configured properly . You may be getting succefuuly installed message but it is not install where it should be. try  pip install --user  i am sure it will work for you. pip install may work fine only in virtualenvironment without any config.Try pip install --user package name

@iosCurator

Answer (score 0):

I had first installed twilio with the `easy_intall` tool

I followed the steps below:

- Uninstall twilio with the command `pip uninstall twillo`
- Install twilio with the command `pip install twilio`
- Close the python IDLE and relaunch it.

Answer (score 0):

For the windows user,

I have suggested, `pip3 install twilio`

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps (on mac):

1. Shift + Command + P
2. search: Configure Language Specific Setting
3. search: Python
4. add: "code-runner.runInTerminal": true

That's it!

Ask me any question about it by:
[My LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/in/mehdiparsaei/)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when using poetry for my dependency management. Poetry doesn't recognise it as an existing package yet, hence it won't run your code unless you try the poetry+pip way.

Answer (score -2):

there will be 2 reasons for this

1.make sure you kept right path for python files in environment location

2.install twilio
commands:
1.pip3 install twilio
(or)
pip install twilio
2.python otpv.py